# Numero de linhas no DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Tenho um  DataGridView e preciso que ele me mostre em uma textbox o número total de linhas que contémo  DataGridView.

como posso fazer isso.

Abaixo segue meu codigo

```
private void ListaGrid()
    {
        string strSQL = @"SELECT
                          CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(SC.C5_EMISSAO AS DATE), 103) AS [EMISSÃO PED.],
                          SC.C5_NUM AS PEDIDO,
                          CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(SF.F2_EMISSAO AS DATE), 103) AS [EMISSÃO NF.],
                          SC.C5_NOTA AS NF,
                          SC.C5_XCLIDES AS CLIENTE,
                          SC.C5_VOLUME1 AS VOLUME,
                          S4.A4_NOME AS TRANSPORTADORA
                       FROM SC5020 AS SC
                       INNER JOIN SF2020 AS SF WITH (NOLOCK) ON SF.F2_DOC = SC.C5_NOTA
                       INNER JOIN SA4020 AS S4 WITH (NOLOCK) ON S4.A4_COD = SC.C5_TRANSP
                       WHERE SC.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' AND SC.C5_NOTA <> ''
                       AND SF.F2_EMISSAO BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime,'" + txtDtInicial.Text +"', 103) AND CONVERT(datetime,'"+ txtDtFinal.Text +"', 103) ORDER BY SF.F2_EMISSAO";

        //conexao = new SqlConnection(conm);
        comando = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conm);

        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter dados = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
            DataTable dtLista = new DataTable();
            dados.Fill(dtLista);

            dgPedidoDiario.DataSource = dtLista;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando a propriedade [`RowCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowcount(v=vs.110).aspx) do `DataGridView`.

Exemplo:

```
textbox.Text = dgPedidoDiario.RowCount.ToString();
```

[Link para conhecimento](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowcount(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Posso dar uma melhorada na sua resposta?

Comment: Claro que pode, é sempre bom

Comment: Valeu. Não fiz nada demais, só expliquei a propriedade e adaptei o código =D

Comment: Ficou bem melhor assim :)

Comment: Deu certinho aqui obrigado.